# Launching Ktor app via Docker causes: No Koin Context configured. Please use startKoin or koinApplication DSL

Tags: docker, kotlin, ktor, koin

I'm trying to launch my Ktor backend app in Docker. But I have an exception on app start:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Koin Context configured. Please use startKoin or koinApplication DSL. 
        at org.koin.core.context.KoinContextHandler.getContext(KoinContextHandler.kt:29)
        at org.koin.core.context.KoinContextHandler.get(KoinContextHandler.kt:35)
        at org.koin.ktor.ext.KtorApplicationExtKt.getKoin(KtorApplicationExt.kt:34)
        at com.widgets.ApplicationKt$module$$inlined$inject$1.invoke(KtorApplicationExt.kt:77)
        at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
        at com.widgets.ApplicationKt$module$4.invoke(Application.kt:117)
        at com.widgets.ApplicationKt$module$4.invoke(Application.kt)
        at io.ktor.auth.Authentication.configure(Authentication.kt:77)
        at io.ktor.auth.Authentication$Feature.install(Authentication.kt:165)
        at io.ktor.auth.Authentication$Feature.install(Authentication.kt:148)
        at io.ktor.application.ApplicationFeatureKt.install(ApplicationFeature.kt:68)
        at com.widgets.ApplicationKt.module(Application.kt:116)
        at com.widgets.ApplicationKt.module$default(Application.kt:91)
```

This is my Application code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    embeddedServer(Netty) {
        module {
            install(Koin) {
                modules(
                    module {
                        single<Logger> { BackendLogger() }
                    },
                    ApiInjection.koinBeans
                    // ...
                )
            }
            apiModule()
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}

@kotlin.jvm.JvmOverloads
fun Application.apiModule() {
    val userApi by inject<UserApi>() // when this dependency used - I have a crash
    // ...
}
```

When I launch my app locally (Intellij Idea) all works fine. So why Koin installing doesn't work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

After long researching finally I've found solution.

I added this line to `build.gradle` file:

```
application {
    mainClassName = "com.mypackage.ApplicationKt"
}
```

And also I edited `resources/application.conf` file:

```
    application {
        modules = [ com.mypackage ]
//        modules = [ com.mypackage.ApplicationKt.module ] // previous version
    }
```

So it helps me! And I hope it can help you!